# Going back to previously working component gives white page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Doing my first steps with [VueJs](https://vuejs.org/) these days and got [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) and some components up and running using [`vue-cli`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to get a proper scaffold.

I extended the router's definition (`./router/index.js`) as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import Welcome from '@/components/Welcome';
import NewMails from '@/components/NewMails';
import Settings from '@/components/Settings';
import Bugreport from '@/components/Bugreport';


Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'welcome',
      component: Welcome,
    },
    {
      path: '/newmails',
      name: 'newmails',
      component: NewMails,
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'settings',
      component: Settings,
    },
    {
      path: '/bugreport',
      name: 'bugreport',
      component: Bugreport,
    },
  ],
});
```

I built a navigation component as follows:

```
<template>
  <section class="hero is-small is-info">
    <div class="hero-head">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <span class="title is-3" style="margin: 10px 0 0 32px">Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-end">
            <router-link to="welcome" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active">
              <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
            </router-link>
            <router-link to="newmails" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active">
              <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open"></i></span>
            </router-link>
            <router-link to="settings" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active">
              <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></span>
            </router-link>
            <router-link to="bugreport" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active">
              <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i></span>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {

};
</script>
```

As you can see, navigating between the different views is done via the router by using its [`router-link` element](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html).

When the application is loaded the `/` route is activated and the `Welcome` component is injected to the DOM as desired. In addition toggling between the `newmails`, `settings` and `bugreport` views resp. components works quite nice.

However, when trying open the `welcome` route on the `/` path again the desired component does not be injected properly. Instead of the contents I was able to see on my initial look at the same component, I am getting a white/blank page only.

Inspecting the app's DOM shows that the component's contents are not injected, instead a

```
<div id="app"><!----></div>
```

is all I get leading to the mentioned blank page.

Despite of running in development mode, VueJs does not log any error messages to the browser's console, which makes debugging a bit nasty at this point. Googling around lead to several similar issues telling that a blank page occurs when invalid HTML is rendered by Vue. So I compared the faulty component with the other ones and could not find any major difference. In addition I tried to replace the component itself by e.g. adopting the route's definition to:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'welcome',
      component: Settings,
    },
    {
      path: '/newmails',
      name: 'newmails',
      component: NewMails,
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'settings',
      component: Settings,
    },
    {
      path: '/bugreport',
      name: 'bugreport',
      component: Bugreport,
    },
  ],
});
```

Which literally results in the same effect. The component is rendered/injected correctly at its first visit, and results in the faulty `<!---->` when coming back from another route/view/component.

What am I doing wrong here since all other routes are working as desired?

Comment: How are you navigating back to the `welcome` route? Are you manually changing the URL in the address bar or are you clicking the `router-link`?

Comment: @Phil: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to do. However, combining [Richard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007715/3991125) and [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007230/3991125) with a [redirecting statement](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html) results in the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a route for `welcome`, only for `/`.

So why should `<router-link to="welcome">` do anything?

Here's a couple tips:

-Use either a redirect or an alias to fix your `welcome` routing problem.  https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html.

I recommend an alias.

> An alias of /a as /b means when the user visits /b, the URL remains
>   /b, but it will be matched as if the user is visiting /a.

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'welcome',
  component: Settings,
  alias: '/welcome'
}
```

-Use absolute paths instead of relative paths in your `<router-links>`

```
<router-link to="/newmails">
```

Reason being, if you're in a nested route like `/welcome/home/dad` and you click `<router-link to="newmails">`, it will route to `/welcome/home/newmails` instead of `/newmails`

-Lastly, if you're using vue-router and you ever see `<div id="app"><!----></div>`, it's most likely an unmatched route.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use named routes, but the syntax is different (note the colon before `to`).

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'welcome'}">Welcome</router-link>
```

Ref: [Vue Named Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html)